# What is the equivalent of cold storage or paper wallet for NXT?

Tags: coldstorage, brain-wallet, nxt

I want to be able to secure my [NXT](http://nxt.org/cryptocurrency/faqs-about-nxt-cryptocurrency) in cold storage. What are some ways of doing this?

Since NXT is only accessible via a brain wallet, I can just store the passphrase on a paper, but what if I wanted to see it as a watch-only address? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but quite more difficult than with Bitcoin.

All NXT tokens/coins are stored on the network, but it is possible to create an account "offline" that is secured by a 256-bit public key and does not expose your private key to the network.

There is [a step-by-step tutorial on the NXT-Forum](https://nextcoin.org/index.php/topic,3973.msg37591.html#msg37591).

Comment: so your saying you can just generate an address with an offline computer even though the blockchain isnt even downloaded? but dont you have to go online to send a transaction in order to secure it better with 256bit encryption?

Comment: I'm no expert in nxt but the tutoria seems pretty decent so try it out ;)